# How to connect sql developer to XAMPP MYSQL server

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp, mysql-workbench

I need to connect my sql developer to a localhost XAMPP server

username: root

password: root

hostname: 127.0.0.1

port: 3306

SID: ?

service name: ?

It needs SID or service name. so what are they? and how to know them

Comment: Are you referring to Oracle's SQL Developer?

Comment: yes @Dave.Gugg. it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Download platform independent driver at http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file.php?id=456317
2. Unzip the package and place the file `mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin` in folder `<Path to SQL Developer>\sqldeveloper\extensions`
3. Open SQL Developer and add JDBC driver above in *Extras*, *Preferences*, *Database*, *JDBC Driver of another vendor*:
   [image]
4. Restart SQL Developer and add a new connection (see additional tab *MySQL*): 
   [image]

Comment: I'm happy to help :) I'd appreciate it, if you accept this answer. It also shows to other users that this is a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download mysql-connector-java [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=456317).
2. Paste mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin jar file in following location.
   *your sql developer folder/sqldeveloper/extensions* . 
   (eg: C:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\extensions)
3. Restart Oracle SQL developer.
4. Add jar path in Oracle SQL developer Third Party JDBC Drivers 
   *Tools--> Preferences --> Third Party JDBC Drivers* 
   (C:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\extensions\mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin)
5. Add new connection in Oracle SQL Developer using your required username=root, password and port(=3306).